# Actionscript: objects moving at different speeds that shouldn't be

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

I have a container with several objects added with addchild and the container moves to the left at speed of 0.7. At a certain point, it resets to make it seem like a continuously moving screen.

I want to add another object to the stage at a certain point to move to the left at the same speed and I did so.

However, as they move towards the left, they don't move at the same speed. They get closer and further apart at specific points for some reason, changing their speeds randomly.

Is this a known problem with flash? Could it be because my objects are pretty big with a few alpha layers here and there?

Here's the relevant code:

```
//containers
var bushes:Sprite = new Sprite();
//timer for bushes to reset
var busher = 0;
//speed
var bushspeed = 0.7;
//adds the container
addChild(bushes);
bushes.x = 55;
bushes.y = 312;
var addBush1:parkBush = new parkBush;
bushes.addChild(addBush1);
addBush1.width = 98;
addBush1.height = 73;
var addBush2:parkBush = new parkBush;
bushes.addChild(addBush2);
addBush2.width = 98;
addBush2.height = 73;
addBush2.x += 220;
var addBush3:parkBush = new parkBush;
bushes.addChild(addBush3);
addBush3.width = 98;
addBush3.height = 73;
addBush3.x += 440;
var addBush4:parkBush = new parkBush;
bushes.addChild(addBush4);
addBush4.width = 98;
addBush4.height = 73;
addBush4.x += 660;
var addBush5:parkBush = new parkBush;
bushes.addChild(addBush5);
addBush5.width = 98;
addBush5.height = 73;
addBush5.x += 880;
var addBush6:parkBush = new parkBush;
bushes.addChild(addBush6);
addBush6.width = 98;
addBush6.height = 73;
addBush6.x += 1100;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event){
busher = busher + bushspeed;
bushes.x -= bushspeed;
if (busher >= 221){
bushes.x = 55;
busher = 0;
}
//adding the object
if (timer == 200){
addChild(mau1);
mau1.x = bushes.x + 900;
mau1.y = bushes.y;
mau1.Mau1anim.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
mau1.x -= bushspeed;
```

Comment: Well, I just went without the container and have the objects all move individually. The problem went away but I'm still curious as to why the speeds weren't constant

Comment: You probably did `bushes.scaleX` alteration somewhere else.

Comment: Nah I never used it in the code. It was really weird because it went back and forward but I learned how to use arrays and it's much better now.